# what does tbl = str.maketrans({ord(ch):" " for ch in punctuation}) mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the full code:

```
s = 'life is short, stunt it!!?'
from string import punctuation
tbl = str.maketrans({ord(ch):" " for ch in punctuation})
print(s.translate(tbl).split())
```

I was wondering what `tbl = str.maketrans({ord(ch):" " for ch in punctuation})` means within this code, or in general?

Answer (score 2):

It builds a dictionary of punctuation characters to spaces, translates the string (effectively removing punctuation), then splits on whitespace to generate a list of words.

Step-by-step...first build a character translation dictionary where the keys are punctuation and the replace char is a space.  This uses a dict comprehension to build the dictionary:

```
from string import punctuation
s = 'life is short, stunt it!!?'
D = {ord(ch):" " for ch in punctuation}
print(D)
```

Result:

```
{64: ' ', 124: ' ', 125: ' ', 91: ' ', 92: ' ', 93: ' ', 94: ' ', 95: ' ', 96: ' ', 33: ' ', 34: ' ', 35: ' ', 36: ' ', 37: ' ', 38: ' ', 39: ' ', 40: ' ', 41: ' ', 42: ' ', 43: ' ', 44: ' ', 45: ' ', 46: ' ', 47: ' ', 123: ' ', 126: ' ', 58: ' ', 59: ' ', 60: ' ', 61: ' ', 62: ' ', 63: ' '}
```

This step is redundant.  Although the dictionary looks different, dictionaries are unordered and the keys and values are the same.  What `maketrans` can do is convert character keys to ordinal values, as required by `translate`, but that was already done when creating the dictionary.  It has other use cases as well that aren't used here, so `maketrans` could be removed.

```
tbl = str.maketrans(D)
print(tbl)
print(D == tbl)
```

Result:

```
{64: ' ', 60: ' ', 61: ' ', 91: ' ', 92: ' ', 93: ' ', 94: ' ', 95: ' ', 96: ' ', 33: ' ', 34: ' ', 35: ' ', 36: ' ', 37: ' ', 38: ' ', 39: ' ', 40: ' ', 41: ' ', 42: ' ', 43: ' ', 44: ' ', 45: ' ', 46: ' ', 47: ' ', 59: ' ', 62: ' ', 58: ' ', 123: ' ', 124: ' ', 125: ' ', 126: ' ', 63: ' '}
True
```

Now do the translation:

```
s = s.translate(tbl)
print(s)
```

Result:

```
life is short  stunt it
```

Split into a list of words:

```
print(s.split())
```

Result:

```
['life', 'is', 'short', 'stunt', 'it']
```

Answer (score 0):

`{ord(ch):" " for ch in punctuation}` is a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/).

Those are similar to (and based off of) [list comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/).

[Blog post I wrote explaining list comprehensions](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/)

You can run this code from a Python shell to see what each line does:

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> punctuation
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
>>> punctuation_to_spaces = {ord(ch): " " for ch in punctuation}
>>> punctuation_to_spaces
{64: ' ', 124: ' ', 125: ' ', 91: ' ', 92: ' ', 93: ' ', 94: ' ', 95: ' ', 96: ' ', 33: ' ', 34: ' ', 35: ' ', 36: ' ', 37: ' ', 38: ' ', 39: ' ', 40: ' ', 41: ' ', 42: ' ', 43: ' ', 44: ' ', 45: ' ', 46: ' ', 47: ' ', 123: ' ', 126: ' ', 58: ' ', 59: ' ', 60: ' ', 61: ' ', 62: ' ', 63: ' '}
>>> punctuation_removal = str.maketrans(punctuation_to_spaces)
>>> punctuation_removal
{64: ' ', 60: ' ', 61: ' ', 91: ' ', 92: ' ', 93: ' ', 94: ' ', 95: ' ', 96: ' ', 33: ' ', 34: ' ', 35: ' ', 36: ' ', 37: ' ', 38: ' ', 39: ' ', 40: ' ', 41: ' ', 42: ' ', 43: ' ', 44: ' ', 45: ' ', 46: ' ', 47: ' ', 59: ' ', 62: ' ', 58: ' ', 123: ' ', 124: ' ', 125: ' ', 126: ' ', 63: ' '}
>>> s = 'life is short, stunt it!!?'
>>> s.translate(punctuation_removal)
'life is short  stunt it   '
```

That dictionary comprehension line is basically making a dictionary of ASCII values of punctuation characters as keys and space characters as values. The `.translate` call on our `s` string is then using that dictionary to translate the punctuation characters to spaces.

The `ord` function converts each punctuation character to its ASCII numeric value.

Note that using `ord` and `maketrans` is redundant.  Either of these solutions would work just as well and wouldn't be double translating:

```
tbl = str.maketrans({ch:" " for ch in punctuation})
print(s.translate(tbl).split())
```

or

```
tbl = {ord(ch):" " for ch in punctuation}
print(s.translate(tbl).split())
```